# Document AI Custom Doc Splitter - Internal error encountered

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I created a training set for custom document splitter with a total 3803 docs and 158 labels. I checked with documents quota and limits and all my docs and pages are within the limits. When I run the training I got this following error message

```json
{
  "name": "projects/945951207848/locations/us/operations/4890234249887707766",
  "done": true,
  "result": "error",
  "response": {},
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.documentai.uiv1beta3.TrainProcessorVersionMetadata",
    "commonMetadata": {
      "state": "FAILED",
      "createTime": "2023-10-11T10:41:01.258619Z",
      "updateTime": "2023-10-11T16:41:45.453832Z",
      "resource": "projects/945951207848/locations/us/processors/fd97f52566718e15/processorVersions/43dd9a2405017f3c"
    },
    "trainingDatasetValidation": {},
    "testDatasetValidation": {}
  },
  "error": {
    "code": 13,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "details": []
  }
}
```

I retrained it again, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Update: I disabled half of my labels (79 document type) in the datasets and retrain my model and it successfully passed the training. My follow-up question is, does custom document splitter has limits/quotas on the number of labels and/or number of pages internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with the product development team, and this is due to a product infrastructure issue that is in the process of being resolved.

For this particular instance, reducing the number of docs and labels will prevent the issue from occurring. However, after the issue is resolved, you shouldn't need to reduce the number of docs/labels.

Comment: Thanks Holt Skinner, meaning to say I can even train a model more than 100+ labels after this issue? Just let me know once the team resolve the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Correct, the labels shouldn't have a limit once the issue is resolved.

Comment: Hi Holt Skinner, is the issue regarding the product infra already resolved. I tried to run again with 158 labels and it is still the same internal error. Thanks

Comment: Since last week, the internal error has been resolved, I now I been testing the splitter with 161 categories on my model. Thanks Holt Skinner.

Comment: Sorry I missed your earlier response! I'm glad it's working again